# Add dynamic route in Symfony1.4

Tags: routes, symfony-1.4

I'd like to know, if possible, if I can add/register a new route dynamically, based on some paremeter.

I know that a route is somethig like

```yaml
newsdetail:
    url: /newsdetail/:id/:title
    class: sfDoctrineRoute
    options: { model: News, type object }
    param: { module: articles, action: articledetail }
    requirements: 
        id: \d+
        sf_method: [get]
```

But now, is there a way for me to add, or prepend this kind of route in an action?
My problem is that the module and the action could change depending of the site instance...

So, I've built a component that do something and two different modules, suppose module1 and module2, both two including the component. 
For different reasons, I can't register in the routing file all these routes.
Now, the user1 have to have the route that go to module1, and the user2 have to have the route for the module2.
So, I'd like to add the route in an action.
I hope I have explained it better

Comment: What do you mean by site instance?

Comment: For make it short, for an user could be the module news, anche the action articledetail, and for an other user could be the module anothrnews and the action anotherarticledetail, depending on their credentials

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example about building dynamic route](http://web.archive.org/web/20090311025941/http://www.dfwtek.com/blog/129-dynamic-routes-in-symfony12.html).

Basically:

- you add a listener to the event `routing.load_configuration`
- this listener retrieve routes from the database and prepend them to the current routing cache

Here is a cleaned snippet:

```php
<?php

class frontendConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->dispatcher->connect('routing.load_configuration', array($this, 'listenToRoutingLoadConfigurationEvent'));
  }

  public function listenToRoutingLoadConfigurationEvent(sfEvent $event)
  { 
    $routing    = $event->getSubject(); 
    $products   = Doctrine::getTable('Product')->findAll();

    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
      if (0 == strlen($product->route))
      {
        continue;
      }

      $name  = 'product_'.$product->id;
      $route = new sfRoute(
        $product->route,
        array('module' => 'browse', 'action' => 'catalog', 'product' => $product->id),
        array('product' => '\d+'),
        array('extra_parameters_as_query_string' => false)
      );

      $routing->prependRoute($name, $route);
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

You can retrieve routing from an action using the context:

```php
$this->getContext()->getRouting()
```

So, if you want to add a route from the action, you can do the following:

```php
$route = new sfRoute(
  '/my-route',
  array('module' => 'browse', 'action' => 'catalog', 'product' => 456),
  array('product' => '\d+'),
  array('extra_parameters_as_query_string' => false)
);

$this->getContext()->getRouting()->prependRoute('my-route', $route);
```

Anyway, I still don't **really** understand how you want to make it... Even after your last edit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the snippet. But now, can I do this in a module action?! Or I have to do that necessarily in frontendConfiguration.class.php?

Comment: I think you need to better explain how you plan to update routes in your application, in which case, for which action, user, etc .. So it will be easied to find how to handle it. Update your question instead of posting a comment below.

Comment: ok, question updated. I hope I have explained in a better way

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have the same routing and change the content based on credentials?